# How do I save data into a custom table on form submit?

Tags: forms, 8

Number of columns in my custom table is huge. How do i insert data in custom table on form submit in Drupal 8?
I want to use something similar to `drupal_write_record('table_name', $form_state['values']);` in Drupal8.

Answer (score 5):

As per the [change record](https://www.drupal.org/node/2340291), `drupal_write_record` has been removed, with the new advice being:

> Developers should use [`\Drupal::database()->merge()`](https://www.drupal.org/node/310085), the [Entity API](https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/entity) or one of the provided services, like [key value](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21KeyValueStore%21KeyValueStoreInterface.php/interface/KeyValueStoreInterface/8).

As you're using a custom table, you'll need the first method. An example from that change record:

```
\Drupal::database()->merge('example_deleted_entity_statistics')
  ->key(array('type' => $type, 'id' => $id))
  ->fields(array('count' => $count))
  ->execute();
```

As always, inject the database service if possible, rather than requesting it from `\Drupal`.

Comment: Cannot i use something like $form_state['value'] and store all the values at a time, rather than using fields(array('count1' => $count1, 'count2' => $count2)) .

Answer (score 0):

You can find it under drupal documentation at [Database API Section](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/database-api), for example for insert query check it [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/database-api/insert-queries)

> $connection =  \Drupal\Core\Database\Database::getConnection() ;
>      $connection->insert('mytable')->fields([
>       'title' => 'Example',
>       'uid' => 1,
>       'created' => REQUEST_TIME,
>     ])
>     ->execute();